# posts and attachments, Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$name

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent, undefined

when i try to get the attachment's name like this:

{{$post->attachments->name}}

i get the following error

Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$name (View: C:\wamp\www\Sites\app\views\public\categories\show.blade.php)

**Post model**

```
class Post extends \Eloquent implements SluggableInterface {

    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Category');
    }

    public function attachments(){
        return $this->hasMany('Attachment');
    }

}
```

**Attachment Model**

```
class Attachment extends \Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'type', 'extension', 'user_id', 'post_id', 'size'];


    public function post(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Post');
    }
}
```

**CategoriesController**

```
class CategoriesController extends \BaseController {

    public function show($id, $slug = null)
    {

        $category = Category::find($id);

        $posts = Post::whereCategoryId($category->id)->orderBy('date', 'DESC')->paginate(4);

        return View::make('public.categories.show', compact('category', 'posts'));
    }

}
```

**categorie View**

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
   {{$post->title}} // work fine
   {{$post->body}} // work fine

   {{$post->attachments}} // return this :
       [
         {
            "id":14,
            "name":"29-01-2015-134",
            "type":"image\/jpeg",
            "extension":"jpg",
            "created_at":"2015-01-29 13:04:35",
            "updated_at":"2015-01-29 13:04:35",
            "user_id":1,
            "post_id":134,
            "size":136130
         }
       ]
@endforeach
```

any ideas?!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your relationship definition there can be *many* attachments, that means the relation will return a collection of models. You can either get only the first one:

```
@if($attachment = $post->attachments()->first())
   {{ $attachment->name }}
@endif
```

Or loop over all attachments

```
@foreach($post->attachments as $attachment)
    {{ $attachment->name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you @lukasgeiter for your help  
...Your first suggestion (the first() method ) it’s not working!! When I use the first() method like this     **$post->attachments->first()->name**   it return this error _Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\wamp\www\Sites\app\views\public\categories\show.blade.php)_
I think it’s because in this case we have a **one-to-many** relationship (post and attachments), I realy don’t know!!
...In the other hand, your second suggestion (loop over all attachments) works fine!!
For some reason I don’t know why **$post->attachments->name** isn't working

Comment: You're welcome. The problem with the first one is that if there aren't any attachments it will fail. You'd need to wrap an if statement around it (see updated answer)

Comment: Thanks again @lukasgeiter …yeah, that’s right, the updated answer work now. And it gives the same results as your second suggestion (loop) …I really appreciate what you did…

Comment: Note that it will only produce the same result if you only have none or one attachment. With multiple attachments I recommend the loop. Otherwise you only get the first one. Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer :)

Comment: thank you so much for a great answer. You helped me a lot by explaining the relationship. :)